Closed subgroups of the Cantor group
I'm looking for a description of the closed subgroups $H$ of the Cantor group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}}$ (endowed with the canonical distance $d(x,y) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 2^{-n}|x(n)-y(n)|$) and the quotients $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}}/H$.
I thought they could be written in the form $H = \langle (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \rangle $ where $x_i \cap x_j = \emptyset$ whenever $i \neq j$ but if $x \cap y \neq \emptyset$, $\{0,x,y,x+y\}$ is a counterexample.
I have not found any reference about this subject.

Why do you think closed subgroups have a reasonable  description? For instance, suppose somebody asked you to describe all subsets of $\mathbb N$. What would you answer?
